# Object wiht multi-level nest relationship versioning

Tags: c#, sql, git, database-design, architecture

I have a complex object structure with multi-levels nested relationship that describes a Product configuration. The configuration changes overtime and i need to be able to reference the different configuration at any time in the future. At anytime, the whole system is linked to a specific version of the product and somehow abstract to the whole notion of product versions.

The most straight forward way to implement this, is to clone the whole structure of the product each time a new version is requested and link the different versions together. Is this however an overkill in terms of database load. Is there a better way ?

I also thought of tracking the changes individually and reconstruct the product when a version is requested, but seems quite complex to implement and get right with the multi-level nested relationship.

Or

Save a minimal meta-data in the database to track a version and serialize the whole product structure using tools such as GIT.

Answer (score 0):

VCS tools are not designed for this purpose. This is an application feature (version history) and should be treated as such. The correct way to implement this would be to create an "archive" table for each versioned item type and relate them to the current "actual" item by ID.

Then, whenever the item changes, take its current state and update the archive before you commit the changes to the item to the main item table.

The important distinction to make is that this is not a case of storing a version history for your *C# objects*, it is an application feature for storing a version history of a conceptual end-user "item" in your application. The "product history" and "product object history" are not the same thing; you want to achieve the former. Your object states and the items that they actually represent are two distinct things.

Version control tools like Git are for storing revisions of the *application itself*, not for providing archiving features for the data that the application is consuming. That belongs in a database.

Alternatively, if the issue is being able to roll back your data to a specific point in time, then this should be achieved by taking date-stamped snapshots of your database, which can be swapped out as needed, as this is entirely independent of the application itself.

Comment: I agree with you that is a feature and should be treated as such. An archive as a separate table/repository would store the different versions just fine, however, the whole system should be able to  link to a specific version any time any user chooses to and therefore the database cannot be swapped for that matter to reflect a specific version. Cloning and storing the product in the same table, possibly use partitioning at some point seems to me the only way to abstract the whole system from the existence of the different product versions.

Comment: Then you should be archiving within a single archive table inside the database - if this is something the user can just switch, then you need to start treating this as an application feature, not a database administration/versioning task. Keep track of each version in a ProductArchive table with a ProductID linking to the main product. Then write code to fetch a specific version by date/version number/whatever you need.

Comment: If I go the ProductArchive way, i need to create an Archive table for each dependent table (ProductItems, ProductXXX ....) Or each table  needs to have a ProductID and ProductArchiveID which is totally inefficient :(

Comment: An archive/history table for each type of item that needs to be archived *is* the proper way to do this. Alternatively, you could add a revision number to each existing table and store the history and current product in the same place, but then you'll need separate unique identifiers for each product to identify its revisions and this'll potentially add overhead to retrieving the current version. Either of these approaches will work but, yes, it will take time and effort - a user-readable version history for all of your application data isn't a trivial thing to implement.